# Xeround vs ClearDB hosted MySQL pros and cons?

Tags: mysql, heroku, xeround

We are currently on RDS for hosted MySQL but are considering moving to one of the fault tolerant MySQL addons for heroku. The two main ones seem to be xeround and ClearDB, but I'm having a hard time determining the differences between them. We're mainly interested in fault tolerance, consistent and fast performance and UTF8 charset support. Any experiences with either welcome. There doesn't seem to be much discussion of either out there.

Comment: As of earlier in 2013, Xeround has closed. ClearDB appears to have no competition right now, or does anyone know alternatives to ClearDB?

Comment: Just a note for anyone who might end up here looking for recommendations: I used ClearDB on a project and found out they have an unadvertised maximum # of monthly queries after which they just shut off your access. It's the worst. The project I used them on saw very low average load, then a sudden spike for ~48 hours when it was listed on some sites. We hit the cleardb limit for the month and the site just went down. No warnings, just shut off. Their support didn't think that was unreasonable, so I switched back to RDS. Not recommended.

Comment: Looking around it seems Google SQL is the only other option (other than RDS) but I haven't tried it yet, I am still on traditional MySQL server.

Comment: @IMB Yeah, Google SQL seems to be the only other option vs self hosted, I haven't tried yet. The new t2 burstable RDS instance types are perfect for our latest spiky load project, and cheap for what they provide, so that's worked well. Seems a shame that there's not a Mysql-as-a-service type offering out there though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I struggled with Xeround. We had an app built for none heroku environment that we migrated to Heroku. We tried Xeround but there was some problems with some of our queries for some reason when run against Xeround. Drastic but we ended running a Slicehost mySQL instance. We've recently re-reviewed and found ClearDB to work much better for us so we're now running on that  Db.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that I totally agree with Jhon. I had the same issues. 
I was running my app [play + heroku + xeround ] but some queries where giving me no results, so I switched to clearDB and everything went fine.